# How can a batch file be run on the entire contents of a directory?

Tags: batch-file, audio, directory, command-line-arguments

I am using a commandline program in a batch file to convert different audio formats. However, I'd like to automate the process to read in all the filenames of a folder, and then run the executable on all of the folder's files.

This is the format for the executable (test.exe). '-o' is the argument to output a new file, 'output.wav', from a source file, 'infile.dsp'.

```
start test -o outfile.wav infile.dsp
```

'Outfile.wav' *should* be based on a source file name from the folder. Instead of 'infile.dsp' and **'outfile.wav'**, I should have 'infile.dsp' and **'infile.wav'** in the source folder for each .dsp file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has a few changes: enter the path to the files and path to the exe file.

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\folder\with audio files\"
   for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.* /b /a-d ') do (
      "d:\util\test.exe" -o "%%~na.wav"  "%%a"
   )
popd
```

Comment: This one seemed to work. "%%a" on line 4 needed to have its quotation marks removed, but after that, it worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for /f "delims==" %%i in ('dir "dirTheyAreIn" /b') do (start /wait "" "test -o %%~ni.wav %%i")
```

use % instead of %% at command-line. `;)`

Comment: Could you explain this a bit? Do I need to add in something in "delims==" or change the name of "dirTheyAreIn" or something else?

Comment: change the dirtheyarein to the directory the infiles are in and add the same path in front of the outfile